# Why is express-rate-limit not working as expected?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, express-rate-limit

The problem is that the rate limit is not enforced for the amount of time I specify. Instead of lasting 35 minutes, it lasts for only about 20 seconds. Also, if I keep making the request, the limit is always enforced, so that seems to refresh the time limit, which I think is also unexpected.

Apart from these issues, it works as expected, limiting the number of requests I specify in "max", as long as I make them quickly enough. I have tested locally, and on a Heroku server.

Here is the relevant code:

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var dbRouter = require('./routes/db');

var limiter = require('express-rate-limit');
var app = express();

app.set('trust proxy', 1);

// This is a global limiter, not the one I'm having issues with. 
// I've tried removing it, but the issue remained.
app.use(limiter({
  windowMs: 10000,
  max: 9
}));

app.use('/db', dbRouter);

module.exports = app;
```

db.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var level_controller = require('../controllers/levelController');

var limiter = require('express-rate-limit');

var level_upload_limiter = limiter({
    windowMS: 35 * 60 * 1000,
    max: 1,
    message: 'Too many level uploads. Please try again in about 30 minutes.'
});

router.post('/level/create', level_upload_limiter, level_controller.level_create_post);

module.exports = router;
```

levelController.js

```
exports.level_create_post = [
    (req, res, next) => {
        
        // ...
        
    }
];
```

Comment: You got it so every 9 requests in 10 seconds your rate limit activates.  So just adjust that 10,000 value it's in MS so 1,000 = 1 second.

Comment: For 9 requests, this can activate if you for instance load a page and 5 image requests were made and 3 scripts + html and a further request soon would run the limit. Make not the App.use is ran before many App.$requests so it takes priority over other limits first if used globally so take aim at your global block first. Prevent testing leve/create till solved.

Comment: @BGPHiJACK - clearly you didn't read the comments in the code and you assume this is being used to load web pages with images and scripts

Comment: As I mentioned in the comment, that is not the limiter I'm having an issue with, I left it there just for completeness. The limiter I'm having problems with is in the db.js file, level_upload_limiter.

Comment: The fact is that if you place a middleware in app.use() it will be executed anyway for all routes, so I'm not sure it would work just placing another limiter middleware on top of that.

Comment: @BGPHiJACK I just mentioned that I wasn't having an issue with the global limiter, since it seemed you were focusing on that one. I don't think I was being rude, maybe you confused me with another commenter?

As mentioned I even commented/removed that first limiter, and the issue remained. App.use is run before any requests are made. Even so is there something in your comment that I missed? Honest question, I'm a beginner at node.js and could have missed something obvious.

Comment: Your global limiter will affect that of what you set for your post limiter, as it will act for all requests perhaps wasn't specific enough but your limiter should work if global was turned off no?

Comment: No, it doesn't even if I turn the global limiter off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the typo you made in your settings: <strike>windowMS</strike> -> `windowMs`

Comment: Wow, I checked for typos several times and somehow still missed this. Thank you!

Comment: That's the important of copy/paste :D When I have one code that works but the other doesn't, I just copy the one that's working and paste to the place of that's not working. In this case, I just copy your working code in app and replace it in the db file :D

Comment: Yeah I do that sometimes too, but I guess I was a bit too confident in my visual comparison. It didn't help that I was comparing between 2 different tabs, and I'm not used to the compiler not catching this kind of thing!

Comment: Yup, I had this problem before. Since then I developed another "technique", which paste the code right into the place where it wrong, next step is Ctrl+Z, if you keep the content flashing like that, you will notice the difference. Obviously, it only work for small snippet, just like your app's settings. For larger text, I use diff tools :D

Comment: or more professional, use typescript, will never ever have this problem again